# SFTP/SSH Not Working in Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-touch, sftp

It was working before but now it stopped working. Even in Ubuntu SDK I can't run my application directly to my device...though I'm not sure they are related. The error is:

> Command:  open "phablet@192.168.1.7" 22
>   Error:  Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
>   Error:  Could not connect to server

My device is Nexus 7 2013(flo) with Ubuntu Touch 14.10 r153. I installed it through MultiRom and I actually did a fresh install but still no luck.

Comment: You can get ssh to be verbose by adding `-v` on the command line. The option can be given multiple times to increase verbosity. You  will be able to see which authentication methods there are support at both ends.

Comment: There are/were steps to enable SSH, but they have changed recently. *I will research further.* Meantime, check out: https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/ (which is where the changes were announced. )

Comment: I already enabled it before. I can't see anything from the mailing list about some changes on ssh. I tried this in both WinSCP on Windows and FileZill in Ubuntu so I think it's with Ubuntu TOuch or probably on my network/router?

Comment: ***Did you solve this?*** You needed to read: **[Ubuntu-phone] Developer heads up ... change in ssh handling on the phone** (on 23/05/14 02:51) **Steps:** create SSH key (on workstation), enable SSH on device, copy public key to device, connect.

Comment: I've read that but I still can't figure out how to login vie FileZilla/WinSCP. Same error occurs even if I already loaded the private key in the configuration of FileZilla.

Comment: See [SSH Ubuntu Touch](http://askubuntu.com/questions/601910/ssh-ubuntu-touch/653595#653595) for a working solution. As always with password-less authentication you need to place a `/home/phablet/.ssh/authorized_keys` file (with a public key of the PC you're using to access the Ubuntu Touch device) on your device.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue, on the same tablet. I am currently using the developer channel, but not proposed. OS: 15.04 r2. It won't find my .pem key, however after running the commands below, I was able to get my computer to reject my tablet connecting to it via ssh. Please excuse typos

user@ubuntu:~$ adb shell

phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ android-gadaget-services enable ssh

phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ ssh...

I found out that the build in backup software, which I can't get to work, doesn't allow backup over ssh, if you use the adb interface. The adbd interface does nothing, but acts like it is performing some task.

Comment: Is this an answer to the question? I can't tell.