# SSH Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-touch

I want to SSH my new Ubuntu phone and tried [this instruction](https://askubuntu.com/a/599041/392200) but it doesn't work. I get `"error: device not found"` from every single command.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us exactly what you did. Don't just link to another post, _show us_.

Comment: @user392200 I think you can approve an answer now. Working solutions are provided.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the only thing you need to do to access your Ubuntu Touch device via SSH is place an `authorized_keys` file (with a public key of the PC you're using to access the Ubuntu Touch device) in `/home/phablet/.ssh/`, and enable SSH access via `sudo android-gadget-service enable ssh` in the Terminal app.

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348714/how-can-i-access-my-ubuntu-phone-over-ssh/601972#601972) for an elegant way to get your ssh keys on the device (ignoring the outdated `setprop` instructions).

Once this is done, you may want to have a way to toggle the SSH server state for extra security while roaming in foreign networks:

1. SSH into your device: `ssh phablet@YOURDEVICEIP`
2. Create a folder for your scripts: `mkdir /home/phablet/bin`
3. Fire up nano to create a script: `nano /home/phablet/bin/toggle-ssh.sh`
4. Paste the following:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   if [[ "$(android-gadget-service status ssh)" == "ssh enabled" ]]; then
       sudo android-gadget-service disable ssh
   else
       sudo android-gadget-service enable ssh
   fi
   ```
5. Save the script and exit nano.
6. Make the script executable: `chmod +x /home/phablet/bin/toggle-ssh.sh`

Now you can easily turn your SSH Server on or off by running: `toggle-ssh.sh`, as `/home/phablet/bin` is in the path for your users executables.

**Note:** If you face permission issues of `bash` when executing the script from the device terminal app you need to run: `bash bin/toggle-ssh.sh`

Comment: If you also want to **print the phone's IP address** for convenience I've [created a Gist](https://gist.github.com/bittner/85466c120e7cbe94f4a4) from this script that demonstrates how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another method:

Install ubuntu-sdk (ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa), put your phone in developer mode, open ubuntu-sdk, connect your device to computer, go to devices in ubuntu-sdk and in control, exec open ssh session. And then you can copy your keys, etc, witouth using adb.

Comment: Thanks, when I was in the middle of trying your suggestion, there was [another edit](http://askubuntu.com/a/601972/392200)... looked easier, and it was. Now I can SSH my phone.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue and resolved it with the help of this post:
[Tether Ubuntu bq phone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616245/tether-ubuntu-bq-phone)

If the adb command above fails, it might be because the vendor of the phone is unkown (it was for me in 14.04). In that case find it with

```
lsusb
*Bus 001 Device 010: ID 2a47:0c02*
```

Now add 0x2a47 to `~/.android/adb_usb.ini`

Then restart the adb server after you edited the file with:

```
sudo adb kill-server;  sudo adb start-server
```

Hope that helps,
cheers Andreas

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your information, I finally manage to connect to my phone true SSH.

That's how I did:

1. Install WifiTransfert from the app store;
2. Copy your ssh public key to the phone;
3. add your public key to authorized_key:

   ```
   cat .local/share/wifitransfer.sil/id_rsa.pub > ~/.ssh/authorized_key
   ```
4. Start ssh service:

   ```
   /etc/init.d/ssh start
   ```
5. From there, you can ssh your phone. sudo ifconfig to get the IP address.

   ```
   ssh phablet@IPADDRESS
   ```